# Wi-Fi not connecting

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, disconnect

I have u Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Everything was fine but since last 3 days, after 15-20 minutes of starting my laptop, the internet stops working (no problem with internet because at the same time it's working perfectly on other devices). When i try to disconnect wifi to reconnect it, it doesn't connect. When i turn off wifi and turn it back on, no available networks show.
When i restart my laptop the internet works fine but after 15-20 minutes, same problem occurs again. Please help me. I have my deadlines and it's causing a lot of delay.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520] [1002:6660]
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I did. Please check it before it disconnects again.

Comment: All looks good. It may be a hardware problem like a bad contact.

Comment: I think it looks good because it's working now because i just restarted it to check this post and then i sent you the logs of the above command. I will edit the output (if there's any change) when the internet will stop working.

Comment: @Pilot6 it's happening again and a lot. I mean it never stopped but i wasn't using my personal computer in the past few days. i have tried reinstalling network manager and some other solutions but nothing worked. Wifi gets disconnected and even in that, the output of the command you suggested shows the same output as in question.
When i reboot my system, wifi starts working perfectly.